# Get numerical values from Dataframe column and add them to separate column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas Dataframe as

```
    position base  text
1   458372   A    19:t|12:cg|7:CG|1:tcag|1:T
2   458373   C    21:GCA|3:GCG|3:ATA|2:GCGAA|1:GTA|1:CGAG|1:g
```

I would like to retrieve the numbers from the text column and add them up in another column. Values in the text column contain numbers separated by any non-numerical values `[^0-9]`. In the first row value of the text column, the numbers are 19, 12, 7, 1, and 1, which would add to 40, which would be a value in the new column. The resulting Dataframe would look like:

```
    position base  text                                          text_sum 
1   458372   A    19:t|12:cg|7:CG|1:tcag|1:T                    40
2   458373   C    21:GCA|3:GCG|3:ATA|2:GCGAA|1:GTA|1:CGAG|1:g   32
```

Any clues as to how to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extractall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) for get all numeric, convert to integers and last sum per duplicated index values:

```
df['text_sum'] = df['text'].str.extractall('(\d+)')[0].astype(int).sum(level=0) 
print (df)

   position base                                         text  text_sum
1    458372    A                   19:t|12:cg|7:CG|1:tcag|1:T        40
2    458373    C  21:GCA|3:GCG|3:ATA|2:GCGAA|1:GTA|1:CGAG|1:g        32
```

Or if possible sum values splitted by `|` and then before `:` use:

```
df['text_sum'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: sum(int(y.split(':')[0]) for y in x.split('|')))
print (df)
   position base                                         text  text_sum
1    458372    A                   19:t|12:cg|7:CG|1:tcag|1:T        40
2    458373    C  21:GCA|3:GCG|3:ATA|2:GCGAA|1:GTA|1:CGAG|1:g        32
```

Comment: Hi @jezreal Do you know the advantages of extractall instead of re.findall(r'\d+', text)  ? thanks

Comment: @r.b.leon - Here `df['text'].str.extractall('(\d+)')[0]` return `Series`, not lists, so possible still use pandas functions like convert to integers and sum

Answer (score 0):

An alternative - list comprehension - because they are strings; I'd suggest testing the speed though as the size grows:

import re

```
df.assign(
    text_sum=[sum(int(num) 
              for num in re.split("[:|]", val)
              if num.isnumeric())
              for val in df.text])

    position  base     text                                    text_sum
1   458372     A    19:t|12:cg|7:CG|1:tcag|1:T                      40
2   458373     C    21:GCA|3:GCG|3:ATA|2:GCGAA|1:GTA|1:CGAG|1:g     32
```